# How to create loop that skips cells in VBA from closed sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want the active sheet to add an entry every 4 rows in the C column by extracting cell data from another sheet (as given) every 8 rows (as shown). I have set up what I want but not in a loop format. I want it to keep searching every 8 cells until a fixed amount of iterations (say 12 loops).

Tried setting it up without a loop. Too time consuming as there are many cells to reference

```
Sub Loop_Test1()

' Macro_Test2_CellCapture_721 Macro

    Range("C6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='[EKJV 7-21 Schedule 05-02-19.xlsm]RHP 7-21 '!R42C14"

    Range("C10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='[EKJV 7-21 Schedule 05-02-19.xlsm]RHP 7-21 '!R50C14"

    Range("C14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='[EKJV 7-21 Schedule 05-02-19.xlsm]RHP 7-21 '!R58C14"

    Range("C18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='[EKJV 7-21 Schedule 05-02-19.xlsm]RHP 7-21 '!R66C14"

End Sub
```

Results give what I want but need a loop.

Comment: May I suggest first searching on here, or the web, for vba loop. I'm sure you will find some handy info that will help you answer your question. Once you attempt this, post a new question with your updated code and we can help if its still ot working as intended

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but maybe this will work for you?

```
Sub Loop_Test2()

Dim iterator as long
Dim otherIterator as long

otherIterator=0

for iterator=6 to 18 step 4

    Range("C" & iterator).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='[EKJV 7-21 Schedule 05-02-19.xlsm]RHP 7-21 '!R" & 42 + otherIterator & "C14"

    otherIterator=otherIterator+8

next

End Sub
```